# How to find all the nodes that meet a specific requirement in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to learn neo4j on my own and I would like to ask how I can find all the nodes that satisfy a specific condition. Concretely, let's say that I have a graph and the only relation connecting the nodes is the relation `:FOLLOWS`.

How can I find all the nodes of the graph that have **at least** `k` "followers"?

If I would like to find exactly find all the nodes with **exactly** 2 followers I would do

```
MATCH (a)-[:FOLLOWS]->(n), (b)-[:FOLLOWS]->(n)
RETURN n
```

Either way, the above method seems pretty tedious when it comes to finding all the nodes that have `k` "followers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use predicates in the WHERE clause to add restrictions to narrow down to the data you're interested in.

You can find the number of occurrences of a pattern with the SIZE() function.

Also, using labels on your nodes should help speed up your queries. For this example, I'll assume that :Person is the label for your nodes.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE SIZE( (p)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(:Person) ) = 2
RETURN p
```

You can use inequalities to satisfy your "at least" condition. If you have a between condition, you can chain your inequalities like so:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE 5 < SIZE( (p)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(:Person) ) <= 10
RETURN p
```

which will give you persons with between 6 and 10 followers (inclusive).